# Google Docs API, new "Compare documents" feature available through API?

Tags: google-docs-api

Google has rolled out a useful tool of compare docs.

https://9to5google.com/2019/06/11/google-docs-compare-documents/

I need to access through an API because I'm comparing many documents. I searched through the API reference but didn't find it. Did i just miss it or is it not available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*This feature is not available via the Docs API.*

#### More Information

Fundamentally, the Google Docs API lets you create and modify documents.

From the documentation:

> The API allows you to do tasks such as the following:
>
> - Automate processes
> - Create documentation in bulk
> - Generate invoices or contracts

It is not an API which has methods that directly replicate the methods available in the user interface.

#### Workaround:

The [Revisions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions) resource of the Drive API might be an approximate solution for you, as it allows revisions of documents to be accessed and downloaded via export links.

As Google Documents have some level of version control implementation, it might be possible to use this to make document comparisons. Unfortunately however, there is no direct way of comparing changes, and [as per a recent Issue Tracker case](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156958753) it seems that due to the zip nature of `.docx` files, not even exporting and comparing MD5s can be a direct solution for this.

#### Feature Request:

You can however let Google know that this is a feature that is important for the Docs or Drive API and that you would like to request they implement it. You can use the aforelinked Google's Issue Tracker to report issues and make feature requests for their development services.

The page to file a Feature Request for the Google Docs API is [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=555502&template=1211190) and the Google Drive API is [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=824106)

#### References:

- [Introduction | Google Docs API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/overview)
- [Revisions | Google Drive API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions)

#### Issue Tracker Links:

- [Google Docs export returns non-stable (i.e. different) bytes content for each ex](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156958753)
- [Docs API Feature Request | New Issue - Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=824106)
- [Drive API Feature Request | New Issue - Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=824106)

Comment: Thanks Rafa. I just submitted a request from your link. I hope they add it to the next version of the API. I think the Docs API was just released not long ago... so it will probably be a while. Docs API is only on v1, while sheets is on v4.

Comment: Link to the Feature Request if you want to "upvote": https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157389809